# Maven плагины для сборки

Tags: maven, java

Какие есть плагины для сборки jar? хотелось бы увидеть не только названия но и конфигурацию.

Comment: э.. странно поставлен вопрос..

может тебе  плагин совсем не нужен ?

[mvn package][1] и всё?



  [1]: http://www.apache-maven.ru/lifecycle.html

Comment: вот Вы сначала сами попробуйте, а потом уже отвечайте на вопрос

Comment: это ж не war собрать

Comment: во! теперь я догадываюсь в чём дело.

как  я понял у вас в /project/packaging стоит war

нужно заменить war на jar и всё заработает

Comment: Вы хоть знаете для чего надо jar а для чего war??? зачем всякую ерунду писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, есть плагин [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Имеет ряд нелепых по сути ограничений, но в целом юзабельный.

Comment: спасибо! вот этот плагин помог